how to prevent gif reset when the playback finishes in flutter
I'm using gif_view to control gif in flutter and when it finishes playing, it is coming to initial position, but I want it in last position itself.
import 'package:gif_view/gif_view.dart';

final controller = GifController(loop: false);

GifView.asset(
   "assets/1.gif",
   controller: controller,
   progress: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
),

even it is taking lot of time to load, so I want to fix this also
I'm expecting fix to both loading gif quickly and gif should not reset a after playing completely.

I followed this method for time being and worked for me to avoid reset.
class _GifViewer extends State<GifViwer> {
  bool isPaused = false;
  late GifController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller = GifController(
        loop: false,
        onFrame: (value) {
          if (value == 100)   //<---------- last frame value - 1 
          {
            setState(() {
              isPaused = true;
            });
          }
        });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (isPaused) {
      controller.pause();
    }
    return Scaffold(
      body: GifView.asset(
        path,
        controller: controller,
      ),
      // }),
    );
  }
}


I achieved the same thing using Lottie package.
You can do something like:
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';

and
LottieBuilder.asset(
    "assets/1.json",
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
    repeat: false,   
),

Disclaimer Lottie works for only .json and .lottie files.
For .gif files using gif_view, do:
final controller = GifController(loop: false);
controller.addListener(() {
   if (controller.status == GifStatus.stoped) {
     controller.pause();
   }
});

and
GifView.asset(
   "assets/1.gif",
   controller: controller,
   progress: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
),


will lottie directly read .gif files?
I'm getting error :- malformed JSON at path $

Hey, @HiteshBharadwaj sadly, the package does not works for .gif files. I have updated the answer
